# iPhone Shell - is there any?

Tags: iphone, shell

While working on iphone security architecture, i came to know that i can run applications from other applications in iphone. referring to the following url http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html

for example, i can put a link in a website with following hyperlink 
    skype://
will result skype to run and call at particular number. Now i have few concerns here.

- is there a shell running in background in iphone, so that it allows other application to run basic app commands.
- if the above statement is true then how can i enable or run commands directly into iphone shell?
- if above statements are false, then could you please explain how these commands are being executed?
- is this part of **iPhone SDK**? or this funcationality is **iPhone OS**

Comment: P.S: I am not talking about **jailbroken** iphone :)

Comment: It is part of the SDK. You can ask your application to process a URL. When it does this, it checks the scheme of the URL and does *something*. If the scheme, for instance, is sms:// it will open the Message application. You application can have a scheme and URL as well, in which case it will open that application. It does not execute commands through a shell, and there is no shell unless you do jailbreak your phone an install one.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, tho.

Comment: apology for not posting a programming question, but i found it related to iphone SDK.

I guess iphone has the **safari** browser which is based on standard W3C standards for websites. my question again, the browser sends the URL command to underlying application layer or it handles the link iteself on http/tcp/ip protocol?

secondly, if i put the command *skype://* in browser address bar then it does not work (i.e does not open skype) but if i make it a link in website then it works fine. Can someone explain it?

Comment: It's definitely a programming question in my opinion. You could probably phrase it more like one to avoid anymore close votes. (I'll vote to reopen if it does get closed.)

Comment: It is processed by the springboard, which is the application that is basically the desktop on the iPhone. It is not processed by safari. When you message the UIApplication object to open a URL, the framework forwards that request to the springboard, and it processes the URL. Again, based on the scheme (the part before :// in the URL), it will open some specific application, like Skype. If you do this, however, the springboard will terminate your application before it opens that application.

Comment: @spencer - it is probably a grey area, but in my opinion it is better suited for superuser. He is asking about how the system works, not about any specific API or how to do any programming. He's not even asking about how to script something, just how the iPhone OS works.

Comment: @Jason - True but I think he's asking a question that could require a deeper understanding of the OS that only a developer would be aware of.

Comment: Regarding iPhone shell, see also these questions: http://superuser.com/questions/20071/can-you-get-to-a-command-line-on-the-iphone and http://superuser.com/questions/47295/is-it-possible-to-access-the-shell-darwin-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 5):

This is functionality of the **iPhone OS**.  Applications register themselves as URL Handlers for particular protocols.  In this case the Skype app is registered to handle skype:// URL protocols.

- An Application registers itself as a protocol handler via the CFBundleURLTypes key in it's Info.plist. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).
- The OS reads this key when your application is installed.
- Whenever a URL for that protocol is encountered and tapped on, the OS will launch your App and your Application Delegate will be sent the [application:handleOpenURL:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:) message.
- It is then up to your Application to correctly decode the URL and perform the correct action.

PS.  There is virtually identical functionality available in Mac OS X, with the additional possiblity for URLs to be sent to already running applications.

Comment: that makes sense. One last question to. if i put the command skype:// in browser address bar then it does not work (i.e does not open skype) but if i make it a link in website then it works fine. Can someone explain it?

Comment: That should work, and it works for me.  What OS version are you on?

Answer (score 2):

A shell can be spawned with `system` or `popen` etc. Of course, because the apps are sandboxed, `fork()` is denied so the shell won't be accessible from any AppStore apps.

However, there are lots of stuff running in background on the iPhoneOS. One of them is **SpringBoard.app**, which is the "home screen" you see on start up. Actually SpringBoard.app is responsible for much more stuff than just displaying the home screen, one of them is to receive and deliver URL requests.

The registration process has been described by [@Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433345/iphone-shell-is-there-any/2433346#2433346). But under hood, when a URL request is issued by an app, the following will happen:

1. The app, knowing itself cannot handle a particular URL, calls `-[UIKit openURL:]` to delegate the open request to others.
2. UIKit will package the URL request into a [GSEvent](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GSEvent) (an IPC mechanism), and then dispatch it to SpringBoard.
3. SpringBoard, receiving this GSEvent, calls `-[SpringBoard applicationOpenURL:]`.
4. This method will check if the URL is well-form and safe (stuff like `tel://*5005*78283#` will be rejected, for example). If it is valid, the action will be performed (dial a number, subscribe to a calendar, open an app, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

what alee is asking about, I guess, is the "mailto://". when you put this in the browser address bar it does not do anything, but if you put it as a link and click on it, it lunches the mail app. why does the mail app have this behavior?